# Mesclar array como PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho isso:

```
$categoria_1[0] = array(
    'code' => 'ALI000001',
    'name' => 'Alimento > Arroz
);

$categoria_2[0] = array(
    'code' => 'ALI000002',
    'name' => 'Alimento > Massas
);
```

E preciso deixar assim:

```
$category[0] = [{'code' => 'ALI000001', 'name' => 'Alimento > Arroz},{'code' => 'ALI000002', 'name' => 'Alimento > Massas}]
```

Alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: Usando array_merge($categoria_1, $categoria_2) funciona... Porém se uma das arrays iniciais for NULL, não vai.. Alguma dica...

Comment: Tenta fazer um casting pra ver se vai:  array_merge((array)$categoria_1, (array)$categoria_2)

Answer (score 2):

Mesmo usando o `array_merge`, vais sempre perder uma delas, o melhor que podes conseguir é obter algo semelhante a isto usando o `array_merge_recursive`:

```
array_merge_recursive($el1, $el2);
#saida:
array([code]=>array([0]=>A..01 [1]=>A..02) [name]=>array([0]=>Al...M...s [1]=>Al...> M...s))
```

Porque os elementos de ambas arrays possuem mesmo índice. A menos que as coloques em uma variável como dois grupos distintos.

```
$novo= array();
array_push($novo, $el1);
array_push($novo, $el2);
#saida:
array([0]=>array([code]=>...[name]) [1]=>array([code]=>...[name]))
```

Ou ainda:

```
$novo= array();
$novo[] = $el1;
$novo[] = $el2;
#saida:
array([0]=>array([code]=>...[name]) [1]=>array([code]=>...[name]))
```

Outra forma ainda mais simples, é usando o operador de união `+` em vez do `array_merge`:

```
$novo = $el1 + $el2;
```

Existem ainda outras formas de realizar esse processo, mas a tua pergunta carece de detalhes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$categoria_1[0] = array(
    'code' => 'ALI000001',
    'name' => 'Alimento > Arroz'
);

$categoria_2[0] = array(
    'code' => 'ALI000002',
    'name' => 'Alimento > Massas'
);

$category[0]  = array_merge($categoria_1, $categoria_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php) e [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php):

```
$category[0] = json_encode(array_merge($categoria_1, $categoria_2));
var_dump($category[0]);
```

Retornará:

```
string(94) "[{"code":"ALI000001","name":"Alimento Arroz"},{"code":"ALI000002","name":"Alimento > Massas"}]"
```